# compile boost 1.51.0 on centos6.0 final 64bit

Tags: g++, 64-bit, centos, boost-thread

I compiled boost 1.51.0 on centos6.0 final 64bit(g++ 4.4). there is no error while compiling. however, when I'm trying to link libboost_thread.a to my program, there is a linking error saying 
`undefined reference to`boost::thread::~thread()'`.
I tried nm to list symbols of libboost_thread.a and there is not any symbols named ~thread.

I did the same thing on ubuntu12.04 32bit(g++ 4.6), it worked well and linked successfully without any errors.

Anyone know the issue?

I use boost1.49.0 instead of boost1.51.0, and everything goes well. so I guess there maybe some compatible issue in g++ 4.4 and boost1.51.0

Answer (score 0):

The boost::thread::~thread() function has been inlined in 1.51.  My guess is that you are compiling with 1.49 and linking with 1.51.